# unable to change font size and font weight of picker element derived from native-base for Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

[image]

I am not able to change text size and weigh of picker element
Works perfectly on IOS but not on Android

```js
<Picker 
    supportedOrientations={['portrait', 'landscape']}
    style={[commonStyle.pickerStyle,this.state.isJobEmpty              
            ? {borderColor: 'red'}: null ]}
     textStyle={commonStyle.textStylePicker}
     headerTitleStyle={commonStyle.headerTitleStyle}
 headerBackButtonTextStyle={commonStyle.headerBackButtonTextStyle}
     mode="dropdown"
     placeholder="MAKE A SELECTION"
     placeholderStyle={commonStyle.placeholderStyle}
     note={false}
     itemTextStyle={commonStyle.itemTextStyle}
     selectedValue={this.props.job}
     onValueChange={this.onValueChangeJob.bind(this)}  >
     { jobItems()   }
      </Picker>


var commonStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    pickerStyle: {
        borderRadius: 5,borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#A2AAAD',
        width: 220, height: 60,backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
textStylePicker: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#0074C8',
        fontSize: 20,
        // paddingLeft:100
    },
 headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 30,
        color: '#F2F3F4'
    },
 headerBackButtonTextStyle: {
        color: '#F2F3F4'
    },

 placeholderStyle: {
        color: "#A2AAAD",
        fontSize: 18
    },
    itemTextStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#A2AAAD',
        paddingVertical: 15
    },

})

  const jobItems = () => {
        if(this.state.jT) {
           let jTList= this.state.jT.map((v,i) => {
                return <Picker.Item style={{ fontWeight: 'bold'}} color={"#0074C8"} key={i+1} value={v.jobTitle} label={ v.jobTitle  } />
            });
             jTList.unshift(<Picker.Item color={"#A2AAAD"} key={0} value={jobTitle="MAKE A SELECTION"} label={jobTitle="MAKE A SELECTION"}/>)
            return jTList
        }
    }
```

Look at the below image, picker and input have different text style, so want to increase the font size and font weight of picker "job" and "phasecode" to view better with text from "created by"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`NativeBase Picker` is the implementation of `ReactNative Picker` on `Android`. You can check it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker#itemstyle).

You can use `itemStyle`

```js
itemStyle={commonStyle.itemTextStyle}
```

Comment: oh, it is only for IOS, I need it for android